# scraping data from Chicago Mercantile Exchange website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrape data from table of CME website. Specifically I want to pull the data of Open interest for every future currency. but when I try parse the table it gives me nothing.

Link [from which I am trying to scrape the data](https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/volume-open-interest/fx-volume.html) given below is the code through which I am trying to do it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/volume-open-interest/fx-volume.html"

# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "cmeData voiDataset"})
print(table)
```

Answer (score -1):

Table data comes from another HTML doc that you can get with

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/voi/voi_asset_class_final.xsl&url=/da/VOI/V2/Totals/TradeDate/20201116/AssetClassId/3/ReportType/F?excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB&hidelinks=false&html='

# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "cmeData voiDataset"})
print(table)
```

To get data for specific date you can change URL as below

```
# Date for 2020 November 12
date = '20201112'
url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/voi/voi_asset_class_final.xsl&url=/da/VOI/V2/Totals/TradeDate/{}/AssetClassId/3/ReportType/F?excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB&hidelinks=false&html='.format(date)
```

Comment: i am still getting 'None'. i used the code which you sent me but nothing happened @Jsaon

Comment: i am trying to do a similar search on the volume data in the first table here... https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/us-treasury/10-year-us-treasury-note_quotes_volume_voi.html#tradeDate=20210507       but the data is not apparent in my search. how did you come up with the appropriate url to use

Comment: I used selenum to scrape the values and it worked very well using selenium.

Comment: @user3697498 you can Open Browser -> Press F12 -> Switch to Network tab -> Navigate to [URL](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/us-treasury/10-year-us-treasury-note_quotes_volume_voi.html#tradeDate=20210507) -> Check requests list